# P/Invoke UTF-8 string not being passed correctly and corrupting heap

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am trying to use a C dll within a .Net Framework application using P/Invoke. Here is the signature of the function as declared in the C source:

```cpp
/* extern "C" */ __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall Login(void* handle, 
          const char* username, 
          const char* password, 
          const char* code, 
          const char* appID, 
          const char* cache_path );
```

I have been told by the provider of the dll that all strings used within the API are UTF-8 encoded. Given this information, here is my attempt at a C# equivalent:

```cs
[DllImport("MY_API.dll")]
protected static extern bool Login(IntPtr handle,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string username,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string password,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string code,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string appID,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string cacheDataPath);
```

The `handle` parameter is a `void*` value which I have received from another dll call. I am able to use the `IntPtr` in other dll calls and I get the results I expect. I have verified that I am passing the correct username and password using a command line demo application provided by the supplier of the dll. But when I call this function from my .Net application, two things happen:

1. The return value indicates that I have a bad username or password.
2. Shortly after the function call, my application shuts down with a return code indicating the heap is corrupted.

I have also tried using `UnmanagedType.LPStr`, but that gives the same result.

Unfortunately, the provider of the dll is not familiar with C#/.Net, and can't provide any insight into what is happening here.

Is there something wrong with my C# function declaration?

Comment: `Is there something wrong with my C# function declaration?` - no (apart from the `int`/`bool` return value which should not be relevant for this purpose). Is the provider of the dll [sure](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) that it uses utf-8? Does the dll cache the received pointers for future use?

Comment: `extern bool Login` should be `extern int Login`

Comment: Have you tried specifying `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` in your import attribute?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield How would that affect `LPUTF8Str`?

Comment: _"The return value indicates that I have a bad username or password."_ How did you know that?? The return value is either true or false.

Comment: Some things I would try: Test with UnmanagedType.LPStr, not a final solution but it gives a clue of where the fault might be. Or convert the strings to byte arrays using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() And use a long preallocated byte array, to be sure it is null terminated.

Comment: @shingo Yeah, bad wording on my part. The dll also has a function GetLastError which I used to determine the error value when the function returned false.

Comment: @MennovanLavieren If you read the question, you will see that `UnmanagedType.LPStr` has been tried.

Comment: This works fine, see an output with the "héllo" string properly encoded as UTF8: https://i.imgur.com/NUJtfhk.png you should contact the C developer, maybe he's doing fully things with the strings, or the code you show is not the same as you really have.

Comment: @GSerg My bad. Missed that in the second reading.

Answer (score -1):

Well believe it or not, the first problem was caused by the bool return type. My theory is that the difference between a one-byte bool and a 4-byte int was creating issues with the stack, and my `LPUTF8Str` pointers were garbage. I changed the return type to int and the login worked successfully.

The second problem was apparently caused by calling the Login function within the constructor for the session object I was trying to create. I knew that was an iffy proposition, but I'm building a simple test application and thought I could get away with it.

Comment: No, this type of return value difference could not cause issues on the stack. The return value would be passed in [E/R]AX in all cases.